# fix Swift_TransportException error in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I am trying to make reset Password in laravel 5.4. In env file I have changed

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=*****************
MAIL_PASSWORD=****************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Error shows

Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

## 10060]

How can I fix it? I use mailtrap.io
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the mail port correct? Shouldn't that be 25 ?

Comment: yes.................